# Starting a new instance of chrome, not just a new window with the extension loaded into the new instance

Tags: google-chrome

What chrome command line option is available to start a new instance of chrome with a new chrome process?
I have tried to use --new-window, which only creates a new chrome window for an existing browser process, even though the tab opens in a new window.
However I am interested in having a new chrome process created with the extension loaded into the new instance.
--user-data-dir seems to work in that it creates a new chrome browser process with a new chrome window, but the extension does not get loaded into it.